# How to increase the number of participants registered in single transaction

Tags: civievent

currently the system limit to 10 registrations (including oneself) for a single email.  Can we increase the number?  if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17745) the functionality is in core code, not that I have noticed it, but also it is possible that it only works to reduce the number below 10.

If you are not wanting to capture info details for all the Additional Particants then you should be able to do this via a Price Set field iirc.